# Resizing browser stops width:100% background over css

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website www.onlinemoviesbox.com is having a slight CSS Issue.
When I resize(make my browser width smaller) the vertical scrollbar appears and if I scroll to the right I see that the header background corrupts and does not continue(Black background).
I went over lots of similar questions and wasn't able to fix this issue with similar answers.
I tried removing the header div width from pixels to percentage and that didn't work.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me fix the header so no matter how I resize and scroll I will have the background continued.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include your code for the header div and current css for the div?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What's happening is that your .wrapper is set to width: 100%; which is adapting to the width or your browser so elements like header is adapting to that size. Then you have elements like your slideshow which has fixed widths pushing the browser wider than .wrapper. You'll either have to make the additional element scalable or add min-width: 1170px; to .wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this on your page's HTML:

```
<div class="topheader" style="width:100%;background:#000;">
```

It looks like the width:100% is the problem there.  Try setting a min-width there too, which would be the width where the horizontal scrollbar first appears.

Comment: This Helps... I removes most of the gap but still leaves around 40px... Your can try by yourself... unfortunately not working yet.

Comment: Managed to fix it! There was another div that had 1050px width so I added a min-width to 1050px.

Comment: May I ask why isn't it enough to have width:100% so it will spread all over the browser width?

Comment: The width:100% is the size of the browser WINDOW.  not the size of the content that you can access by scrolling.